# Running a function when user stops entering text

Tags: user-interface, haskell, gtk, signals, gtk2hs

I am writing a small GUI application using Haskell's [gtk2hs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.12.3) library and am currently working with the [multiline text boxes](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gtk/0.12.3/doc/html/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Multiline-TextView.html) within it. I have a function which I want to run when the user makes changes to the text within the text box, but don't want them to have to click a button to activate it.

Furthermore, because it is a rather intrusive and processing intensive function (It draws graphics, loads files etc.), I would like it to fire not whenever a user makes *any* change (which could probably be done with the [bufferChanged](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gtk/0.12.3/doc/html/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Multiline-TextBuffer.html#g:7) signal in text buffer I'm guessing?) but when they stop for a few seconds in between changes.

Basically I am wondering if there is something in gtk which is analogous to the way [range widgets](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gtk/0.12.3/doc/html/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Abstract-Range.html) can have their update policy set to [continuous or delayed](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gtk/0.12.3/doc/html/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Abstract-Range.html#v:UpdateContinuous), but for text boxes

Comment: One way I did a similar thing in wxHaskell was to use a Timer object set at a (configurable) 1 second delay, and enable it every time the user types, which had the effect of delaying by a second after typing has finished. I gave up on gtk, so I'm unfamiliar with it, but maybe you can do something similar using `timeoutAdd` or `timeoutAddFull` and `timeoutRemove` from [Graphics.UI.Gtk.General.General](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gtk/0.12.3/doc/html/Graphics-UI-Gtk-General-General.html).

Comment: Don't know what it is called in the Haskell port, but this is what `g_idle_add()` is for.

Comment: Alternatively (to @AndrewC's suggestion), record the time of last user input, and check against that in a periodic timeout to decide when to run the heavy code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything of the Haskell bindings but in plain C it is quite easy to implement by leveraging a timeout [GSource](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GSource).

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static guint source_id = 0;

static gboolean do_stuff(gpointer user_data)
{
    g_print("doing stuff...\n");
    return FALSE;
}

static void postpone(void)
{
    if (source_id > 0)
        g_source_remove(source_id);
    source_id = g_timeout_add(1000, do_stuff, NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget *window, *text_view;
    GtkTextBuffer *text_buffer;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    text_view = gtk_text_view_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), text_view);

    text_buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(text_view));
    g_signal_connect(text_buffer, "changed", G_CALLBACK(postpone), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

The issue of quitting the TextView before the timeout has elapsed is still open though.